# Authentication error: Using Microsoft Graph planner API in Microsoft Flow to create a plan each time an item is added to a SharePoint list

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I want to create a flow in Microsoft flow that creates a plan in Microsoft planner each time an item is added to a list in SharePoint. 
There is no action in Microsoft flow you can use to create a plan so I decided to use the Microsoft Graph Api where it IS possible to create a plan. With a http action I'm able to call the API
Before you can call the Microsoft Graph API to create a plan you need to follow a few basic steps:

1. Register your app to authenticate with the Azure v2.0 endpoints.
2. Configure permissions for Microsoft Graph on your
   app.
3. Get administrator consent.
4. Get an access token.
5. Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph.

These steps are described into this tutorial: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service.

The description of how to use the create plan in planner graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_plans#example

The problem that i have is that i can't use the access token to call Microsoft Graph. I'm able to perform all steps except step 5 where I need to use the access token to call microsoft graph. Im having a "401" errorcode "unauthorized".
I've been searching to solve this problem for 4 days know but I can't seem to solve it. 
Underneath you can find screenshots of how my flow looks like:

- [general view flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9J95.png)
- [action where I request acces token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXpyt.png)
- [action where I call Microsoft graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxPko.png)
- [Errormessage after calling Microsoft Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W01bd.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace the call Graph to request your profile, if you still cannot do it then it maybe still the configure issue. Although you have register the App but not right configured.

Comment: @SeiyaSu How do i request my profile? I'm very new to all this so excuse me if I'm asking a basic question.

Comment: I didn't make any develop in Office365 in months, but if you are going to work with microsoft flow, i used to read John Liu's blog. It has a nice examples: http://johnliu.net/microsoft-flow/

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below blog to use Graph+MicrosoftFlow,what is missing in your case is get the actual access token:

> https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Flow-Community-Blog/Extend-Microsoft-Flow-with-the-Microsoft-Graph-and-0-code/ba-p/61662
>
> 1. In order to use the Microsoft Graph, we need to define an Azure App that will be authorized via OAuth 2.0 by authenticating directly with
>      Azure AD. Set the permission in here. Store secretid and appid.
> 2. Create flow. To generate the access token, we can use the out of the box Http action and pass the required parameters to the
>      https://login.microsoftinline.com//oauth2/token url. Get the
>      token.
> 3. Use the token to call the Graph.

The full workflow:
[image]

Another reference:

> http://blogopaxio.azurewebsites.net/accessing-graph-api-from-microsoft-flow-using-application-permissions-2/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but it seems the problem lies elsewhere. I tried to implement it like described in the tutorial but it still get the exact same error.

Comment: Token is received correctly, but getting Unauthorized error